# caffe: Debug backward pass in a test

Tags: c++, caffe

I'm trying to code my own loss layer for caffe. However the gradient check does not pass.

For the forward pass, I can get some output using cout or CHECK, but those aren't displayed in the backward pass of the test ! Is there a way to output something from there ?

I also tried using gdb, which I definitely do not master, and could not get it to load the binary AND the source code. Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build your caffe with DEBUG flag (Makefile.config -> uncomment `DEBUG := 1`, then run gdb --args caffe app + parameters, set a breakpoint and let it run.

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40540106/backward-pass-in-caffe-python-layer-is-not-called-working?rq=1).