# I wrote a custom caffe layer. But during training it says "**layer does not need backward computation"

Tags: c++, machine-learning, deep-learning, caffe, backpropagation

I defined a new `caffe` layer, including `new_layer.cpp`, `new_layer.cu`, `new_layer.hpp` and related params in `caffe.proto`. When I train the model, it says:

> new_layer does not need backward computation

However, I do defined `backward_cpu` and `backward_gpu`. I was trying to set `lr_mult` to be not 0. But where should I define `lr_mult` for a custom layer? Except this, is there any other way to make my custom layer execute backward propogation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force caffe to backprop by setting

```
force_backward: true
```

At the beginning of your net.prototxt file. The default behavior of caffe is to compute backwards only when it is certain the gradients are required. Sometimes (especially when there are custom layers) this heuristic is not accurate. By setting `force_backward: true` caffe will compute gradients for all layers in the model (whenever possible).
Read more at the comments in [`caffe.proto`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto#L77-L80).

Regarding [`lr_mult`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto#L315-L316): it is part of the `param` section of the layer - this section is defined for all layers in [`caffe.proto`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto#L340-L342). Thus, you only need to add this clause to your layer definition in the net.prototxt:

```
force_backward: true   # cannot hurt...
layer {
  name: "my_layer"
  type: "MyLayerType"
  bottom: "input"
  top: "output"
  my_layer_param { ... }
  param: { lr_mult: 1 }  # there you go
}
```

You can see more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40540106/1714410).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. And I also figured out why caffe does not execute backward